# How can I do a CSS reset for content going to multiple websites?

Tags: css

I am developing a page that will be distributed to dozens of websites which I have no control over, and it will be shown in a jQuery UI dialog window using a $.load().

Because of this, it is subject to whatever CSS rules are defined on the page. I've been careful to prefix all of my content's id's class names with my company name, to avoid conflicts. But it's common for a site owner's CSS to interfere with my page, for example

```
p { margin: 1000000px; }
```

will make my life miserable. I can obviously do something like

```
#myUniqueContainer p { margin: 5px; }
```

but that doesn't cover every single possible annoyance that may come up.

Is there a good way to reset CSS for my content only, without affecting their page? I'm thinking something like http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ and prefixing everything with #myUniqueContainer

Comment: Is it possible to put your code in an iframe for delivery? This can cause some other issues, but may avoid lots of issues as well.

Comment: you should be able to do `#myUniqueContainer *{/* clean slate */}`, but it's not foolproof, and they can still overwrite your styling.

Comment: I have the same problem with a CMS I built that has inline frontend tools for editing and an always present toolbar if logged in (kind of like wordpress), and an iframe is not a solution. I don't think there's a good solution though, sadly, other than *really* paranoid CSS where you specify every property under the sun with a wrapper like `#my_section` and mark everything as `!important`.

Comment: For your case though, iframe sounds like the way to go.

Comment: Thanks all, yea I started working on an iframe solution yesterday actually, I should have mentioned it in the initial question. I wanted to avoid that because the content in my iframe needs to interact with the parent page (javascript etc). Not impossible since everything is on the same domain, but still a bit of a headache. I think that's what I'll end up doing if I encounter a lot of sites with conflicting CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Well, looks like grouping elements and applying the properties to those groups might be a good idea. I think it will be the easy if you have same margins and padding for the elements in your container. What about to first set all the margins, paddings, and etc.:

```
div #myUniqueContainer * {margin:0; padding:0}
```

From there, all there you will set the properties for all the elements under your `#myUniqueContainer` ID. You